# Real and Imaginary part of f(z) where z=x-iy

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-functions

$$f(z)= exp(\frac{1}{z})$$
hello, i am trying to check if f(z) is analytic using cauchy-reimann equations. please help i am stuck trying to derive the real and imaginary parts. thank you

Comment: Get rid of iota from the denominator and then use the properties of exponential and the fact that $e^{\iota \theta} = \cos \theta + \iota \sin \theta$ to get real and imaginary parts.

Comment: thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice:
$$z=x-jy$$
$$\frac1z=\frac{1}{x-jy}\frac{x+jy}{x+jy}=\frac{x+jy}{x^2+y^2}$$
Now we split it up, since:
$$e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$$
$$f(z)=\exp\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)\exp\left(\frac{jy}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$
we also know that:
$$e^{ja}=\cos(a)+j\sin(a)$$
and so:
$$f(z)=\exp\left(\frac x{x^2+y^2}\right)\left[\cos\left(\frac y{x^2+y^2}\right)+j\sin\left(\frac y{x^2+y^2}\right)\right]$$
finally we can break this up to get:
$$\Re(f(z))=\exp\left(\frac x{x^2+y^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac y{x^2+y^2}\right)$$
$$\Im(f(z))=\exp\left(\frac x{x^2+y^2}\right)\sin\left(\frac y{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

---

The cauchy-Riemann equations state that if:
$$f(z)=f(x+jy)=u(x,y)+jv(x,y)$$
the function must satisfy the equations:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
for our equation we have:
$$u(x,y)=\exp\left(\frac x{x^2+y^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac y{x^2+y^2}\right)$$
$$v(x,y)=\exp\left(\frac x{x^2+y^2}\right)\sin\left(\frac y{x^2+y^2}\right)$$
so now simply calculate these derivatives.

Comment: thank you very much, I have done it in terms of r and theta. I understand it now. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If $z = x - iy$ then
$$
\frac1z = \frac{1}{x-iy} = \frac{x+iy}{x^2+y^2},
$$
and $x^2+y^2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can you complete this now?

Comment: yeah, thank you very much.